# Type error in arcpy SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor

I'm trying to use arcpy SearchCursor to iterate through an attribute table, and the only fields that I'm interested are line_code, w_min and ang_ataque.
This is not running properly because I got the type error :

> "'Row' object is not iterable"

What's wrong in my code?

```
import arcpy
featureClass="C:\\Users\\andreia.medeiros\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Trabalho\\Modelo\\linhas_150_5km.shp"

data=arcpy.SearchCursor(featureClass,"","","Line_code;w_min;ang_ataque","Line_code;w_min;ang_ataque")

import collections
d=collections.defaultdict(list)
for Line_code,w_min,ang_ataque in data:
     d[Line_code].append(w_min*ang_ataque)
```

Comment: where do you get the error? maybe the shapefile is empty. make sure all the fields exists in the shapefile

Comment: My shapefile has an attribute table with various fields. I get the error after cycle for. I'm gonna update the code here to show

Comment: What version of arc are you using? If 10.1 or above, this would be easier using the arcpy.da cursors.

Comment: When using "w_min*ang_ataque", if one is text, you could get a type error!

Comment: sorry not to mention, my arcgis is 10.0
w_min and ang_ataque are float and double type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the row object first, then you can get the field values. So you can't say:

```
for Line_code,w_min,ang_ataque in data:
...
```

Instead, try changing your loop to:

```
for row in data:
     d[row.Line_code].append(row.w_min*row.ang_ataque)
```